# Creating and printing user list in JAVA

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to store users in list. And then print them(name is enough) but i cant figure how.

```
private List userList = new ArrayList();
....
customer = new User(firstName,lastName,idNumber,email,officialAddress,postAddress);
userList.add(customer);

for(int i=0;i<userList.size();i++){
    System.out.println(userList.get(i));
}
```

This is how I am adding a user to list and printing. But in printing I cant print name or something else (i have getters like `getFirstName()` but it  simply won't work like  `System.out.println(userList.get(i).getFirstName());` I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: show us the line declaring that List. Did you declare it as List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>(); ?

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: @fpezzini Added

Comment: @Michael Kreutz yes cannot resolve method.

Comment: You need to use Generic, do `List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();` If not, the code thinks the list is filled with Object, so your method of User class canno't be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
private List userList = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because you're using raw type, which is [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html), therefore it wouldn't know the real type of `User` when you get from the list.

See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).